# Is it possible for the forward pass computed by a wrapper to not agree with a hard coded using MatConvNet?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, matlab, conv-neural-network

I was implementing a super duper simple network and I wasn't able to have the forward pass match for both the wrapper and the hardcoded version of the network:

```
clc;clear;clc;clear;
%% prepare Data
M = 3;
x = zeros(1,1,1,M); % (1 1 1 2) = (1 1 1 M)
for m=1:M,
    x(:,:,:,m) = m;
end
Y = 5;
r=Y;
%% parameters
L1 = 3;
w1 = randn(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 L1) = (1 1 1 3)
b1 = ones(1,L1);
w2 = randn(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 L1) = (1 1 1 3)
b2 = ones(1,L1);
G1 = ones(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN scale, one per  dimension
B1 = zeros(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN shift, one per  dimension
EPS = 1e-20;
%% Forward Pass
z1 = vl_nnconv(x,w1,b1); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M)
bn1 = vl_nnbnorm(z1,G1,B1,'EPSILON',EPS); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M)
a1 = vl_nnrelu(bn1); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M) 
z2 = vl_nnconv(a1,w2,b2);
y1 = vl_nnpdist(z2, 0, 1);
loss_forward = l2LossForward(y1,Y);
%%
net.layers = {} ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv1', ...
                           'weights', {{w1, b1}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'bnorm', ...
                           'weights', {{G1, B1}}, ...
                           'EPSILON', EPS, ...
                           'learningRate', [1 1 0.05], ...
                           'weightDecay', [0 0]) ;                       
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu', ...
                           'name', 'relu1' ) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv2', ...
                           'weights', {{w2, b2}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pdist', ...
                           'name', 'averageing1', ...
                           'class', 0, ...
                           'p', 1) ;
fwfun = @l2LossForward;
bwfun = @l2LossBackward;
net = addCustomLossLayer(net, fwfun, bwfun) ;
net.layers{end}.class = Y;
net = vl_simplenn_tidy(net) ;
res = vl_simplenn(net, x);
%%
loss_forward = squeeze( loss_forward ) % (1 1)
loss_res = squeeze( res(end).x ) % (1 1)
```

Does someone know why this might be? It seems very mysterious to me.

---

It seems it only happens when the Batch Normalization (BN) layer is included. Is there an additional randomization that I am not aware of that is used in the BN layer?

check it out yourself:

```
clc;clear;clc;clear;
%% prepare Data
M = 3;
x = zeros(1,1,1,M); % (1 1 1 2) = (1 1 1 M)
for m=1:M,
    x(:,:,:,m) = m;
end
Y = 5;
r=Y;
%% parameters
L1 = 3;
w1 = randn(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 L1) = (1 1 1 3)
b1 = ones(1,L1);
w2 = randn(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 L1) = (1 1 1 3)
b2 = ones(1,L1);
G1 = ones(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN scale, one per  dimension
B1 = zeros(1,1,1,L1); % (1 1 1 3) = (1 1 1 L1) BN shift, one per  dimension
EPS = 1e-20;
%% Forward Pass
z1 = vl_nnconv(x,w1,b1); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M)
bn1 = z1;
%bn1 = vl_nnbnorm(z1,G1,B1,'EPSILON',EPS); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M)
a1 = vl_nnrelu(bn1); % (1 1 3 2) = (1 1 L1 M) 
z2 = vl_nnconv(a1,w2,b2);
y1 = vl_nnpdist(z2, 0, 1);
loss_forward = l2LossForward(y1,Y);
%%
net.layers = {} ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv1', ...
                           'weights', {{w1, b1}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
% net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'bnorm', ...
%                            'weights', {{G1, B1}}, ...
%                            'EPSILON', EPS, ...
%                            'learningRate', [1 1 0.05], ...
%                            'weightDecay', [0 0]) ;                       
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'relu', ...
                           'name', 'relu1' ) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'conv', ...
                           'name', 'conv2', ...
                           'weights', {{w2, b2}}, ...
                           'pad', 0) ;
net.layers{end+1} = struct('type', 'pdist', ...
                           'name', 'averageing1', ...
                           'class', 0, ...
                           'p', 1) ;
fwfun = @l2LossForward;
bwfun = @l2LossBackward;
net = addCustomLossLayer(net, fwfun, bwfun) ;
net.layers{end}.class = Y;
net = vl_simplenn_tidy(net) ;
res = vl_simplenn(net, x);
%%
loss_forward = squeeze( loss_forward ) % (1 1)
loss_res = squeeze( res(end).x ) % (1 1)
```